# How to get row id or parameter from dataurl in jqgrid to create a dynamic select list to edit row

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

I have an ASP.NET website with a C# back-end that uses Jqgrid.

I want users to be able to select an item in the grid to edit. One of the fields that can be edited will be presented to users as a drop-down selection list with only valid options for that user.

For example, let's say I have a grid displaying persons. If "person1" is edited, the user may be able to choose "blue" or "red" from the selection list for this item, but if "person2" is edited the user may only choose "yellow" or "green" from the selection list.

I want to dynamically populate the selection list based on what person/row is selected.

I have editoptions and dataurl set on the specific field as follows:

```
editoptions: { dataUrl: 'FetchData.aspx' }
```

Yet, I somehow need some kind of parameter to pass to the FetchData.aspx page so that it can do its background-checking on the specific person and create the correct list for the specific "person".

I was hoping I could pass the rowid or itemname or something as follows to identify the specific row/item that is selected:

```
editoptions: { dataUrl: 'FetchData.aspx?selecteditem=' + Id }
```

How can I pass a parameter so that I can create the correct list of items for the specific item? There are countless similar questions on the web, but I haven't been able to find a conclusive answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the problem by adding the following onSelectRow function (note that 'Id' in the below code represents the name of a column I want to pass as parameter. It can be any column name in your grid) :

```
onSelectRow: function (id) {
  var temp = $("#list").getRowData(id)['Id']
  $("#list").setColProp('mySelectListColumnName', { editoptions: { dataUrl:'FetchData.aspx?selecteditem=' + temp });
}
```

The above helps to pass the parameter. However, this alone is not sufficient - it allows FetchData.aspx to receive a parameter and customize the html response accordingly, but it only fetches the values once from the dataUrl - so it doesn't refresh when I select different rows.

To solve this, I have also added the following statement:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, { recreateForm: true });
```

This ensures that the edit form will be recreated every time that edit is clicked, which is what I want since the edit form will be slightly different for each row. Works perfectly. Hope this helps someone out there - there is a maze of options out there and this is the simplest I've seen. And it works.

Comment: Hi Stanley, yes, I implemented it in this way, but it does not seem to be the "clear" solution...I mean the select list is loaded firstly, and then, after 1-2 seconds the select list is rendered again. In my case the select list is jumping while the user try to change something. Do you have the same phenomenon?

Comment: No - for me this is working perfectly. It sounds like you might be triggering your loading function for data for the list from some form editing event and this gets overridden by some other form editing event. Have a look on http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing to understand the sequence in which the "events" are performed. This might help explain why it behaves irrationally. But like I say, I did not encounter similar problems.

Comment: Take a look here http://jqgrid-multiselect.heroku.com/. You can see the delay in populating of the select-field. I have the same problem. No matter which method I use: onSelectRow or beforeInitForm. And you don't have it?

Comment: The reason for the delay is because to populate the list, jqgrid makes an asynchronous ajax call to the application to fetch the data to populate the list with. So the form is rendered while ajax is still busy fetching the data in seperate web requests in the background. Yes, my app also works like this. To prevent this "waiting" while list is populated you can use a static list of options, but if list must be dynamic you will have to fetch the data as you do. Possibly you could delay rendering the form until ajax has finished receiving data by making ajax request synchronous (async=false).

Comment: Yes, the problem is solved by ajaxSelectOptions:{async:false}. It takes a bit longer, but it does not "jump". I prefer this. Thank you for advice!

Comment: The next problem is the functionality of onclickPgButtons. If you click on a Next/Prev-Button it is immediately firing onSelectRow, but it does not populate a new select list. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: I solved this problem too. The solution is `'afterclickPgButtons' => "function(whichbutton, form, rowid) {
var box_no = grid.getRowData(rowid)['box_no'], url;
url = 'selectlist/?cmd=c_archivebox&q=getSelectedFilms&value='+box_no+ ' option';                        $('#selected_film_id').load(url);
}"`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your defaults:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.jgrid.edit, { recreateForm: true });
```

and this to your grid parameters:

```
ajaxSelectOptions: {
    data: {
        selecteditem: function() { return $('#list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); } }
}
```