# Delay while using dataUrl

Tags: jqgrid

I use the dataUrl option to fill the select list and I noticed a delay in loading of selectlist options. You can see the problem here http://jqgrid-multiselect.heroku.com/
I am wondering whether it is "normal" or not?

UPDATE:
For a second I have the form like this:
[image: first view]

and then

[image: second view]

it looks not very good, if the edit form "jumps" like this. The width of the select list changes too.

Comment: I am not seeing any delay, I am getting between 80-200ms for the selectlist load.

Comment: First of all you should post some code before asking a question.Now i experience delay for sure which makes me wonder why are you including so many script tags, I mean for multi select you dont need to, just make multiselect true in jqgrid properties, jqModal.js, jqdnr.js?? why?

Comment: I am not a developer of this given example. I found it on internet. But I used the same application logic. I do not think the problem is too many scripts because we have same scripts for both views.

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be solved by ajaxSelectOptions:{async:false}. More details can be found here [How to get row id or parameter from dataurl in jqgrid to create a dynamic select list to edit row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523579/how-to-get-row-id-or-parameter-from-dataurl-in-jqgrid-to-create-a-dynamic-select/11535220#comment16062202_11535220)